# Buscar no BD com For Repetição

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte Tabela como Exemplo:

```
data - chave primaria, contendo a data mesmo 2018-01-02.
diasemana - int, contendo o dias das semana tipo 1 para segunda, 2 para terça.
semanaAno - int, contendo o numero de semana do ano tipo 1 primeira semana do ano.
```

Então tenho:

```
<?php
$repetiacao = 3;
 for ($i = 0; $i <= $repetiacao ; $i++) {
    // aqui está o problema
 }
?>
```

"Aqui está o problema": eu queria que cada laço de repetição ele pegasse a data, por exemplo 2018-01-02 no primeiro laço depois 2018-02-02 no segundo e por último 2018-03-02, de acordo com a quantidade de repetição

Como veem ele aumenta o MÊS em cada repetição porém ainda o meu `echo` eu preciso que seja o campo `semanaAno` da minha tabela. Então Cheguei a lógica mais ou menos que em cada laço eu faço um `select` na tabela mostrando o `semanaAno` quando `data = data`. Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

A partir da data você consegue contar o número de semanas. Para isso você pode usar a classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php) e a função [format()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.format.php). Além disso é interessante conhecer os valores usados para [formatar](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Seu codigo pode ficar assim:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
   $data = new Datetime('2018-' . $i . '-02');

   echo '<br><br>';
   echo 'data: ' . $data->format('Y-m-d');
   echo '<br>Semana do ano: ' . $data->format('W');
   echo '<br><br>';
}
```

Isto imprimr:

```
data: 2018-01-02
Semana do ano: 01



data: 2018-02-02
Semana do ano: 05



data: 2018-03-02
Semana do ano: 09
```

Onde o W retorna o número de semanas. Você pode conferir outras opções de formatação aqui no [php.net](http://%3C?php%20%20for($i%20=%201;%20$i%20%3C=%203;%20$i%20%20)%7B%20%20%20%20$data%20=%20new%20Datetime('2018-'%20.%20$i%20.%20'-02');%20%20%20%20%20echo%20'%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E';%20%20%20%20echo%20'data:%20'%20.%20$data-%3Eformat('Y-m-d');%20%20%20%20echo%20'%3Cbr%3ESemana%20do%20ano:%20'%20.%20$data-%3Eformat('W');%20%20%20%20echo%20'%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E';%20%7D).

Mais um detalhe, se você for consultar a documentação passada, você verá que o primeiro dia da semana é a segunda-feira, para a opção W.

Comment: Otimo, vou testar aqui e retorno, muito obrigado

Comment: Caro Juven_v, sim deu certim para oque eu preciso, caso eu queira pegar tambem o dia da semana de cada laço ficaria como? exemplo 2018-02-02 seria uma sexa-Feira no caso numero 5

Comment: eu coloquei o $data->format('N'); como ví na documentação. Está certo? Seria isso mesmo?

Comment: Sim, está correto

Comment: Então tudo certo, Obrigado.

Comment: Mas uma pergunta e se o Ano tiver dinamico, exemplo eu começo em dezembro de 2018 e mando repetir 3 vezes, automaticamente ele teria que pular para 2019

Comment: Você poderia usar a função `add()` da classe `DateTime`, exemplo disponivel [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.add.php). Então, a variavel `$i` do laço for não precisaria ser concatenada com a data. O avanço da data seria feito com a função citada.

Comment: vou consultar e retorno obrigado